# why cant windows programs run on linux without an emulator?

Tags: linux, windows

I have been searching on Google this for a while but every answer so far is telling me how to run it (with an emulator), but I want to know windows programs cant run on Linux like how you just click them to open them on windows.

Comment: This is not a tech support website, this website is about programming, and your question has nothing to do with that.

Comment: "I've got an engine part for a Honda, why doesn't it work in my Toyota?"

Answer (score 0):

Windows programs often use the Windows API (windows.h) which provides the features like creating a graphical window and adding buttons to it. This API is not available in linux which has its own libraries for those sorts of things.

On top of that windows uses a different executable format than linux. If the code is only standard C/C++ it could be compiled for both but the windows executable would still need an emulator because of the file format differences.